# JSON nested objects parsing with BodyParser in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have a node.js server that is receiving this JSON object as a put:

```
{
     stats = {
          abdominal=0,
          bicep=0,
          deltoids=0,
          erector_spinae=0,
          gastro_soleus=0,
          gluteus=0,
          hamstrings=0,
          lat_dor_rhom=0,
          obliques=0,
          pectoralis=0,
          quadriceps=0,
          trapezius=0,
          triceps=0
     },
     name=Name,
     _id=userid,
     level=1,
     experience=200
}
```

I use this chunk of code to try and access the data:

```
user.name = req.body.name;
user.level = req.body.level;
user.experience = req.body.experience;

user.stats = {
     abdominal: req.body.stats["abdominal"],
     bicep: req.body.stats["bicep"],
     deltoids: req.body.stats["deltoids"],
     erector_spinae: req.body.stats["erector_spinae"],
     gastro_soleus: req.body.stats["gastro_soleus"],
     gluteus: req.body.stats["gluteus"],
     hamstrings: req.body.stats["hamstrings"],
     lat_dor_rhom: req.body.stats["lat_dor_rhom"],
     obliques: req.body.stats["obliques"],
     pectoralis: req.body.stats["pectoralis"],
     quadriceps: req.body.stats["quadriceps"],
     trapezius: req.body.stats["trapezius"],
     triceps: req.body.stats["triceps"]
};
```

The name, level, and experience values update just fine but accessing the stats object's members doesn't seem to work. When I do a simple `console.log(req.body["stats"]["abdominal"]);` I get an `undefined` as a result. `console.log(req.body["stats"]);` does work, though, and prints out the whole object. Any thoughts about why accessing these variables isn't working?

Comment: What you are describing as a "JSON object" is not JSON nor an object. Valid Javascript objects are of the form `{key: value}` but not `{key = value}`.  Is that what is logged if you console.log `req.body`? Also, since none of the keys for the stats property are variables you should use dot notation to access them: `req.body.stats.abdominal`. You could also just assign the entire property reference: `user.stats = req.body.stats;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't solve the problem but I decided there was really no benefit to having a nested object so I just made it all one layer. This fixed the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  it turns out I was not using the correct ContentType (my client code was posting application/x-www-form-urlencoded)... so, the form body parser was parsing the content.

switching to posting the correct content (e.g json) *and* including the correct ContentType header (e.g. Content-Type: application/json) fixed the issue of having the body include properties like you described (NOTE: if you use something like jquery specifying the ContentType option will do both for you).

It is interesting to note, however, that I am still having issues with an object that is nested in another object (objects 'nested' in an array seem to work fine).

e.g. client sends:

`

```
{
    "someObj": {
        "someChild": {
            "someProp": "0"
        }
    },
    "someChild": {
        "someProp": "0"
    }
}
```

`

server parses
`

```
{
    "someObj": {
        "someChild": { }
    },
    "someChild": {
        "someProp": "0"
    }
}
```

`